# Wifi not working on startup

Tags: raspbian, wifi, internet

I am using ethernet cable to ssh into raspbian, which also has a wifi dongle attached. When I reboot raspbian, it does not connect to wifi and on the desktop in the upper right corner there is an icon which says "dhcpcd not working". If I start dhcpcd manually it connects to wifi without any issues, I can then disconnect ethernet cable and ssh to it through wifi.

But I want to make it connect to wifi automatically, so that I don't have to use the ethernet cable anymore. Is that achievable?

My interface file looks like

> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto eth0
>
> allow-hotplug eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> auto wlan0
> allow-hotplug wlan0
>
> iface wlan0 inet manual
> wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
>
> iface default inet dhcp

Comment: Your Pi has a wireless dongle to presumably talk to a wireless router.  The wireless router should be acting as the DHCP server and give the dongle an IP address.  You should not need to start a server on your Pi.  What is this dhcpd program you are starting?

Comment: @joan Sorry, I'm new to linux. I was using windowed mode through vnc and in the upper right corner of the desktop on rpi there was an icon which said "dhcpcd not working". When I start dhcpcd this icon gets reply by wifi logo and everything connects normally.

Comment: I'm afraid that means nothing to me as I don't use VNC.  Hopefully someone will come along who understands what is going on.

Comment: I don't think that this has anything to do with VNC, pretty sure that if I connected an external monitor to rpi it would show me the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with: lxde and DHCPCD is not running. I could correct by opening a terminal window and entering $ sudo dhcpcd, but this wasn't persistent across reboots.

When your system is starting, do you see:

- [FAIL] Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces ... failed!
- [FAIL] defines some interfaces that will use a DHCP client ... failed!

These will appear after DHCPDISCOVER and just before your X terminal starts. Use ctrl-s to stop the display, and ctrl-q to continue.

If you see this, then to correct, open a terminal:

$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

and replace dhcp with manual. The two lines from your interfaces are:

- iface eth0 inet manual
- iface default inet manual

then reboot

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issue i was able to fixed running these commands:

```
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service
sudo systemctl reboot
```

the issue seems to be that is that `dhcpcd.service` is being installed in some update and is not compatible with `/etc/network/interfaces`